Logrotation in windows
I'm using windows os and using a c program which runs in background all the time. The logs are stored in a file but the file size is getting huge and it's hard to debug. Even some editor also takes time to load the file. I'm thinking of rotating the log and keeping a few older log files in archived state and a few months old can be removed. In linux we have logrotate utility there is windows version of it logrotatewin but Is there any other available package for windows?
